# OS X contains heapsort in stdlib.h which conflicts with heapsort in sort library

Tags: c, sorting, shared-libraries, heapsort

I'm using Ariel Faigon's sort library, found here:
http://www.yendor.com/programming/sort/

I was able to get all my code working on Linux, but unfortunately, when trying to compile with GCC on Mac, its default stdlib.h contains another heapsort, which unfortunately results in a conflicting types error.

Here's the man page for Apple heapsort:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/heapsort.3.html

Commenting out the heapsort in the sort library header causes a whole heap of problems. (pardon the pun)

I also briefly thought of commenting out my use of stdlib.h, but I use malloc and realloc, so that won't work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isolate your use of Ariel Faigon's function in a single, tiny file that does not need to use `<stdlib.h>`.  Make sure you link Ariel Faigon's library before the standard C library.

Comment: This seems like a lot of bending over backwards to make this work.

Comment: @Chris - yes, and no.  The file might consist of two `#include` lines, one for the project's own declarations, the other for the desired heapsort's declarations, and a function that might occupy 4 lines.  Plus comments, etc.  The function itself simply relays the calls through.  Frankly, this can be easier than modifying the build process to vary the compilation flags used for compiling different source files.  And, once done, the code will seldom if ever need changing.  If you have a simpler solution, propose it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`:

```
$ gcc -E /usr/include/stdlib.h | grep heap
int heapsort(void *, size_t, size_t,
int heapsort_b(void *, size_t, size_t,

$ gcc -E -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE /usr/include/stdlib.h | grep heap
# No output at all this time
```

Hopefully `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` won't suppress anything that you need.

You can often get around these sorts of problems with some combination of `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, `_KEEP_YOUR_STUPID_EXTENSIONS_OUT_OF_STANDARD_HEADERS`, ... Sometimes they fight each other though so you're left with source partitioning schemes as Jonathan Leffler suggests.

Comment: Better would be to compile with `-ansi -pedantic` or whatever command-line options turn off non-standard declarations in standard headers.

Comment: @Chris: most people **do want** POSIX functions declared in the C headers, just not additional pollution.